# String of raw data to Char Hex Array for Bitmap

Tags: esp32, adafruit, string, ble

I'm trying to transfer a monochrome ~4kb image file over WebBT to an ESP32 via BLE.

The EPD display looks for an unsigned char array to represent a bitmap. So..it should be in the format of something like

```
`const unsigned char epd_bitmap_123_1 [] PROGMEM = {
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};`
```

I've been successfully able to chunk, serialize, and reassemble an ArrayBuffer of the image from JS to the mcu in C++ (as a String).
I can verify that printing the Hex String on the board is the same as what's given from JS.

However, the image does not display properly on my EPD.

```
    class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
     //String value of raw data from JS ArrayBuffer..I can only get data as String with BLECharacteristic...
     std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

     //Converting of String above into a Hex String
     string s2;
     stringstream ss;
     for (const auto &item : total) {
       ss << hex << int(item);
     }
     s2 = ss.str();

     //Converting Hex String into Char Array for EPD
     char * const cstr2 = new char [s2.length()+1];
     std::strcpy (cstr2, s2.c_str());

     //Displaying final Char array on EPD
     display.clearBuffer();
     display.drawBitmap(0,0,(unsigned char *)cstr2,296,128,EPD_BLACK);
     display.display();
};
```

Any idea what's going wrong here? I'm thinking it's something with encoding.

Comment: The display doesn't want a hex string. It wants pure binary data. the `0xff` and similar are only the human representation in the code. It corresponds to the binary representation `0b11111111`.

Comment: So the display works when passing something like `const unsigned char epd_bitmap_123_1 [] PROGMEM = {
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};` 

I was hoping `//Converting Hex String into Char Array for EPD
     char * const cstr2 = new char [s2.length()+1];
     std::strcpy (cstr2, s2.c_str());` would result in something of that format, but it does not appear to be working correctly.

Comment: EPD expects monochrome bitmap. So I get this is just array of bits representing either black or white.

Official doc says its expects a `byte[]` http://adafruit.github.io/Adafruit-GFX-Library/html/class_adafruit___g_f_x.html#a805a15f1b3ea9eff5d1666b8e6db1c56

So I guess my confusion is how a `const unsigned char []` can be a `byte[]`.

Regardless..how can I then convert anything I have (original string version of raw data, or subsequent converted Hex string) into said Byte array?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of misunderstanding of the fundamental C++/Arduino programming concepts, 1)`epd_bitmap_123_1 []` is not a string (a string is an array of unsigned char **terminated** by a `\0` in C++), it is an array of `unsigned char` (a.k.a. `uint8_t` in C++, or `byte` in Arduino). 2) When passing in an array to a function as an argument, C++ automatically pass in the pointer of the array, so there is no need to cast it with `(unsigned char *)`.

Comment: If the `Adafruit_GFX::drawBitmap()` is expecting a `const uint8_t bitmap[]`, it would be easier that you just declare your `epd_bitmap_123_1 []` as `const uint8_t epd_bitmap_123_1 [] PROGMEM` so that no casting is required.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification, I understand it wants a Byte array now. The problem is that I'm sending over an ArrayBuffer of bytes, but my BLE callback can only obtain a string representation of this. Printing out this string representation yields bunch of weird chars (mostly backwards '?')...

So..converting that string to a Hex string does in fact get the same bytes that were present from the JS array buffer. How to then convert this hex string into a byte array?

Comment: Note: The converted hex string I get would just be in format of "FFFF", as opposed to, "0xFF, 0xFF".